# How would magic controlled insects go about repairing a magical scarf?

Tags: science-based, bio-mechanics, insects

### About the Question

The end questions are about the mechanics of the repair work itself for certain parts of the scarf.
Everything else should be explained below.

### Location

On one of the worlds of a Binary Planet, a civilization has developed Saturn 5 like rockets. They are attempting to explore/exploit their sister planet.
(both planets are earth-like and habitable)

On the sister planet, no civilization has been observed from orbit or by probes. However, ground exploration teams uncover a group of Druids.

The Druids are mostly peaceful but, they do have a fighting class of Rangers for protection.  (The visitors are aggressive in nature)

### How The Scarf Works

This is from a 1960's technology point of view.

The Druid Rangers seem to have "magical" scarfs that move almost like water.  The scarfs can deflect the bullets or "reach out and catch/slow" them (ie absorb the momentum by caving in) before the bullets hit the target.

Think: Spawn's cape, Kill-la-Kill's Kamui, and the green witch from 47 Ronin

If caught in the wrong spot, the scarf can recieve damage, such as tear or bullet hole, etc. This is only because the scarfs aren't what the Druids would call "Military Grade". From a distance, a visiting Scout observes a Druid repairing a scarf (that has minor damage) using mostly insects.

### Magic Explanation: controlling the insects

- The Druid Rangers have the equivalent of a Samsung Galaxy S42 Active with Near Field Telepathy Communication [NFTC].
- One of the apps allows the user to have 100% control of nearby insects
- NFTC can also influence (not 100% control) some nearby animals like rabbits. (Wolves/bears/etc. need NFTC repeaters that look like talisman)
- NFTC interacts with the brains of the Druids to provide an Augment Reality UI instead of a "touch screen".

This should help limit your answer to what is/isn't possible.

### Source of the Druids Magic

The world that the Druids are on is actually a "4H Summer Camp" for an advanced (eg Type 3) civilization.

The Druids are the camp staff. There are no kids; its off-season.  The Rangers are rent-a-cops: no guns, no military-grade gear.

The visitors are actually the descendants of an "Amish-like colony" of that advanced civilization. They look identical to the Druids; "Prime-Directive" like rules don't apply.

Unlike a Leisure Planet (Star Trek: Original), there is no "interior complex" to the planet. The camp is a "primitive camp" within the boundaries of said "Amish-like Colony"

### Magic Explanation: the scarf

- The scarfs also have NFTC in addition to a series of computer+sensors built throughout the scarf.
- With the NFTC, the Rangers can control the scarf as if it were an extension to their body.
- The information from the computer+sensors are fed back (telepathically) to the end-user giving the end-user "6th sense" abilities.
- The computer+sensors that are built into the scarf allow the scarf to react to slow (< mach 3) bullets autonomously.
- This means that the Druid's control of the scarf is more for strategical purpose.
- The movement of the scarf is done via bio-locomotion (eg reflex muscles) directly controlled by the series of computer+sensors
- The outer wrapping of the scarf (the part that is seen) is a mixture of high tensile strength polymers (eg Kevlar like material) and carbon nano-tubes

Not only do the insects have to repair the textile component of the scarf, the insects should be able to help repair the bio-mechanical and computer+sensor components.

### Known repair steps

- If there is too much damage, the scarf will need to be replaced.
- Ants/centipedes are used to clean/remove damaged areas - including the reflex muscles.
- Genetically engineered spiders are used to produce silk that is easy for other bugs to work with. (ie not sticky)
- Cockroaches' abdomens are used to store the nano-bots that are needed to repair the computer+sensors.
- Fresh organic material (eg from the "sacrifice" of a rabbit) is used to supply the raw materials needed to repair/replace the biological component of the scarf.

### Unknown repair methods - ie the questions

Assume the insects resmble Earth insects.  Some minor adjustments are allowed.
The answers need to fit within the style of what has been described.
Being from an advanced civilaztion, some handwaving is allowed.

1. How do the insects do the repair/replace of the "reflex muscles"?  I'm concern with connecting new tissue to existing tissue.
2. How do the insects do the final stitching/sewing of the outer layer?
3. How do the insects make a patch of cloth for the larger damaged areas? (or is that the cut-off for repair/replace?)

The more variaty of insects used, the better.
The more exotic the insects are, the better.

Tags - I think this question should have a "textile" tag.
Let me know if it should have any other tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## How do the insects do the repair the "reflex muscles"?

Since spider's silk a pretty complex protein in itself, it is within the realm of reasonable for an advanced spider-bot to be able to make all sorts of other proteins. In that case, they spider bots can generate constituent muscle fibres that you need.

Assuming that the scarf has the bio-engineered ability to heal itself, then when spiders place compatible muscle fibers against damaged areas, the scarf should be able to integrate them. Now, speed up this process with some advanced healing factor and we are done.

## How do the insects do the final stitching of the outer layer?

A variety of bugs sew. [Weaver ants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weaver_ant) or [orb-weaver spiders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orb-weaver_spider), for example. Simply use one of them to do the final stitching.

## How do the insects make a patch of cloth for the larger damaged areas?

Well, bugs can make some pretty large complex objects. Single spiders can make webs meters across. Ants might be particulary appropriate for this purpose, since colonies organize themselves to hold leaves into certain positions before they start weaving them together. They could easily do this with fragmented pieces of scarf, while muscle fiber spiders extrude the bits needed to patch everything back together.

[image]

Comment: Your link for Weaver Ants points to Spider Silk.

Comment: @MichaelKutz Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Your description made me think of weaver ants. They create hives from leaves by pulling cooperatively and then glue them together using their larvae, which can excrete silk.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weaver_ant

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Could you explain why you think weaver ants might meet the requirements of the question?